# Where can I download the latest DVD ISO which contains everything?

Tags: downloads, dvd

Where can I download a DVD ISO which contains everything? Am I right, the ISOs on the download sections are CD ISOs only which contains the OS and the most basic applications?
Thanks...

Comment: The latest version of Ubuntu, Ubuntu 13.04 is too big to fit on a CD. You can download it from www.ubuntu.com which you can get to by clicking the [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) link at the top left-hand corner of the Ask Ubuntu webpage that you are looking at right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

This link has both the stable release (12.04) and most recent newer release (13.04) and is too big to fit on a CD.  You'll need a DVD or USB stick to burn.

Choose your flavor, and architecture, and you're good to go!